# While loop with hasNext method as condition keeps throwing ArrayOutOfBounds Exception? (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, file, bounds, out

I'm working on a username/password login using GUI. I'm using a while loop with a hasNext() extension to the file name as the condition to store the information that's in the file into an array so that I can compare the user's input to the information that's stored in the file. Then I use an if statement to do the comparison. If there's match, then the program redirects the user to another class or method, otherwise it doesn't do anything.

The problem is that I keep throwing an ArrayOutOfBounds exception as SOON as it tries to read the *first* line from the file.

I threw in a System.out.println(userLogin[i]) to see if it looped all the way through, but it must not since the line never outputs. My guess is that it stops first thing once it gets into the while loop. How do I fix this? Your help is greatly appreciated. If you need me to clarify the question, please say so in your comment and I'll re-edit my post to be as clear as possible. This is my code as follows:

```
    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        String usernameInput = "";
        char passwordInput[] = {};

        if(e.getSource() == okButton){
            usernameInput = usernameTF.getText();
            passwordInput = passwordTF.getPassword();
            try{
                verifyLogin(usernameInput, passwordInput); //sends input to be verified
            }catch (IOException ed){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There was a problem " +
                        "retrieving the data.");
            }
        }else if (e.getSource() == cancelButton){
            setVisible(false);
            dispose();
        }
    }

}
```

That was the class and method that is supposed to send over the user's input for username and password over to the method that checks if there's match to what's stored in the file.

This is the method that verifies whether the input has a match:

```
public void verifyLogin(String username, char[] password) throws IOException {
    File myFile = new File("Accounts.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile);

        while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
            int i = 0;

            this.userLogin[i] = inputFile.next();
            System.out.println(userLogin[i]);  //says this is where the OutOfBounds occurs
            this.passLogin[i] = inputFile.nextLine();
            this.passwordCheckLogin = this.passLogin[i].toCharArray();

            if((this.userLogin[i] == username) && (this.passwordCheckLogin == password)){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Access Granted");
                inputFile.close();
                break;
            }

            i++;

        }


}
```

The information in the file is written in this manner (username on the left followed by the password on the right):

```
John001 bananas
Mike001 123chocolate
```

Thank you!

Here's the whole code, sorry for not including it earlier. Hopefully this helps you guys better understand my question. Thank you again for taking the time out to answer.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class DeskLogin extends JFrame {

private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 200;
private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 300;
private JLabel usernameLabel;
private JLabel passwordLabel;
private JButton okButton;
private JButton cancelButton;
private JTextField usernameTF;
private JPasswordField passwordTF;
private JPanel loginPanel;
private String userLogin[] = {};
private String passLogin[] = {};
private char passwordCheckLogin[] = {};



public DeskLogin(){
super("Login");
setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
setVisible(true);
buildPanel();
add(loginPanel);

}

private void buildPanel() {
usernameLabel = new JLabel("Username: ");
passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password: ");
usernameTF = new JTextField(10);
passwordTF = new JPasswordField(10);
okButton = new JButton("OK");
cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");

loginPanel = new JPanel();

loginPanel.add(usernameLabel);
loginPanel.add(usernameTF);
loginPanel.add(passwordLabel);
loginPanel.add(passwordTF);
loginPanel.add(okButton);
loginPanel.add(cancelButton);


okButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
cancelButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
}

public void verifyLogin(String username, char[] password) throws IOException {
File myFile = new File("Accounts.txt");
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile);

inputFile.useDelimiter(" ");

    while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
        int i = 0;

        this.userLogin[i] = inputFile.next();
        System.out.println(userLogin[i]);
        this.passLogin[i] = inputFile.nextLine();
        this.passwordCheckLogin = this.passLogin[i].toCharArray();

        if((this.userLogin[i] == username) && (this.passwordCheckLogin == password)){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Access Granted");
            inputFile.close();
            break;
        }

        i++;

    }


}

private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    String usernameInput = "";
    char passwordInput[] = {};

    if(e.getSource() == okButton){
        usernameInput = usernameTF.getText();
        passwordInput = passwordTF.getPassword();
        try{
            verifyLogin(usernameInput, passwordInput);
        }catch (IOException ed){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There was a problem " +
                    "retrieving the data.");
        }
    }else if (e.getSource() == cancelButton){
        setVisible(false);
        dispose();
    }
}

}








}
```

Comment: I doubt the exception is on the line you state, since you access that index in the line above it.  Nevermind the obvious mistakes (`i` is always 0, e.g.).  Can you give us a self-contained snippet of code that actually demonstrates the problem?  What you've given us is a rough copy that doesn't faithfully reproduce your code.

Comment: Is the array `userLogin[]` properly declared and initialized ?

Comment: Where do you fill userLogin[] array and how long is it?

Comment: Since you are always setting `i=0` and `this.userLogin[i] = inputFile.next();` is working then there is no way that `System.out.println(userLogin[i]);` will give `IndexOutOfBoundException`.

Please revisit your code. The problem is somewhere else.

Also `i++;` towards the end is useless as `i` is getting set to `0` in the beginning.

Comment: the return type ofor next() is String. how userLogin[i] is working? is userLogin[] is array of Strings?

Comment: did you check whether accounts.txt is in the same working directory

Answer (score 0):

How about you try changing the line to read `System.out.println(this.userLogin[i]);`? My guess is that you have two variables named userLogin, one of which is local to this function (the other being an instance variable). `this.userLogin` is not the same as `userLogin`. Apologies if I am off. No offense intended.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you set userLogin to a zero length array and never increase it:

```
private String userLogin[] = {};
```

Therefore accessing any element of userLogin should throw an exception.  It doesn't really have anything to do with the `inputFile.next()` call.  You could do an isolated `userLogin[0] = null` and it should blow up.

I suggest you use an ArrayList or other dynamically sized structure that you can build up incrementally.

Answer (score 0):

You have these 3 setup as arrays, but you never use them as arrays and you also never use them outside of verifyLogin.

```
private String userLogin[] = {};
private String passLogin[] = {};
private char passwordCheckLogin[] = {};
```

This will need additional code, but should get you going in the right direction
I've created local variables for those 3 and adjusted the code to use them.

```
public void verifyLogin(String username, char[] password) throws IOException {
    File myFile = new File("Accounts.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile);
    String userLogin = null;
    String passLogin = null;
    char[] passwordCheckLogin = null;

    while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
        userLogin = inputFile.next();
        if (inputFile.hasNext()){
            passLogin = inputFile.next();
            passwordCheckLogin = passLogin.toCharArray();
        }
        else {
            //Need to alert that we have an improperly formatted Accounts.txt
            break;
        }
        if((userLogin == username) && (passwordCheckLogin == password)){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Access Granted");
            inputFile.close();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't need a scanner. A BufferedReader is simpler. You can use split to break your words in a line. Also, note the placement of the stream close (at the end). Also I have rejigged the conditional using *equals* rather than *==*. Finally, a String.valueOf to allow the char array to be compared with the String.

```
File myFile = new File("Accounts.txt");
BufferedReader inputFile = new BufferedReader(
       new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(myFile)));

String line;
while ((line = inputFile.readLine())!=null) {
    int i = 0;

    this.userLogin[i] = line.split(" ")[0];
    System.out.println(userLogin[i]);
    this.passLogin[i] = line.split(" ")[1];
    this.passwordCheckLogin = this.passLogin[i].toCharArray();

    if (this.userLogin[i].equals(username) 
      && String.valueOf(this.passwordCheckLogin).equals(password)){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Access Granted");                
        break;
    }

    i++;    
}
inputFile.close();
```